# Extracting the "value" field from the insights node using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using this query for extracting the number of total impressions and unique paid impressions.

```
me?fields=posts.limit(1){insights.metric(post_impressions_unique,post_impressions_paid_unique)}
```

However i only want to retrieve the "value" field, so i can get rid of all the unnecessary nodes. I have used:

```
    me?fields=posts.limit(1) 
   {insights.metric(post_impressions_unique.value,post_impressions_paid_unique.value)}
```

and i'm getting the following error.

```
     "(#100) The value must be a valid insights metric".
```

I have also tried the following:

```
  me?fields=posts.limit(1){insights.metric(post_impressions_unique.as.(unique_impressions),post_impressions_paid_unique.as(unique_paid_impressions))}
```

which does not work either. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce it to the `values` structure, but not below that so that only the `value` property inside that would be returned. (And `id` will always be included, no matter what.)

```
me?fields=posts.limit(1){insights.metric(post_impressions_unique,
          post_impressions_paid_unique).fields(values)}
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Can’t see much point in doing so, though. You’d lose the connection which value was for which metric to begin with, and should the order they are returned in change for some reason, you’d have a problem.

And fixing that again, by using the Field Aliasing syntax, `.as(…)` - possible maybe, but then you’d kinda be increasing the length of the request you’re sending to begin, in exchange for that slightly shorter response … I think you’re rather trying to “optimize” in a place that doesn’t warrant that to begin with here.

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe for your reply. Indeed i have tried and it did not solve the problem. Basically i want the same effect for counting insights data, as say when counting shares. So for example, i am looking for a similar query to shares.summary(true), but for counting insights data. I want it to be in that format because it makes it a lot easier to me when doing the processing later. Thank you

Comment: To add to the above, i want something that have this effect: insights.metric(post_impressions_unique).fields(values.fields(value)) , but i don't know how to make it work

Comment: You can not get the data in just any arbitrary format you might like, you’ll have to make do with what exists. Transform it to something else first after receiving it, if you like, if that makes further processing easier.

Comment: Hi thank you for you reply. I understand what you are saying. Is there a way to exclude fields, though? That could solve the problem, right?

Comment: No, there is not really a way to exclude any fields, it works the other way around, that you ask for the ones you want.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for all of your help. Ill accept your answer